# Is there a natural map $\Omega^1_X\to N^{\vee}_{Y/X}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth complex manifold and $Y\subset X$ be a complex submanifold. Is there some natural map from $\Omega^1_X$ to $N^{\vee}_{Y/X}$?

Comment: Could you explain your motivation for this? Why do you want such map? You always have the zero map.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Probably only if the exact sequence $0 \to TY \to TX \big|_Y \to N_{Y/X} \to 0$ splits, and even in that case the map may not be natural.

Comment: @user40276  The motivation is to dualize the exact sequence (3.15) on page 65. http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2009/1805/1805.pdf